# Display buttons in the middle of the screen in BlackBerry 10 app using qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I wanted a screen in my application which should look like this:

[image]

This means the button in the screen should appear in the centre for screen both horizontally and vertically.

Does anyone how to do it. I have written the following code but its not working.

```
Container *contentContainer = new Container();
contentContainer->setLayout(StackLayout::create());  
//contentContainer->setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment::Center);
contentContainer->setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment::Center);

Button* submitButton =  new Button();
submitButton->setText("Submit");

Button* cancelButton =  new Button();
cancelButton->setText("Cancel");

contentContainer->add(submitButton);
contentContainer->add(cancelButton);

Page * testPage = new Page();
testPage ->setContent(contentContainer);

Sheet *testSheet = new Sheet();
testSheet->setContent( LoginSheetPage );

testSheet->open();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it center , First you have to create container with docklayout() and inside this container, you have to create stacklayout() with buttons and set docklayout() container as a content of Page.

```
Container *contentContainer = new Container();
contentContainer->setLayout(StackLayout::create());  
contentContainer->setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment::Center);
contentContainer->setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment::Center);

Button* submitButton =  new Button();
submitButton->setText("Submit");

Button* cancelButton =  new Button();
cancelButton->setText("Cancel");

contentContainer->add(submitButton);
contentContainer->add(cancelButton);

Container *rootContainer = new Container();
rootContainer->setLayout(DockLayout::create());  
rootContainer->setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment::Fill);
rootContainer->setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment::Fill);
rootContainer->add(contentContainer);

Page * testPage = new Page();
testPage ->setContent(rootContainer);
```

Comment: I think there some mistake after you have created the `rootContainer`

Answer (score 0):

When you need to specify where your content needs to be docked you should use [DockLayout](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__docklayout.html). Then you set the vertical and horizontal alignment properties on it's children depending on where you want them to be docked. In your case:

```
Container *sheet_container = Container::create().layout(DockLayout::create());
Container *button_container = Container::create()
            .layout(StackLayout::create())
            .horizontal(HorizontalAlignment::Center)
            .vertical(VerticalAlignment::Center);
Button *submit_button = new Button();
submit_button->setText("Submit");
Button *cancel_button = new Button();
cancel_button->setText("Cancel");
button_container->add(submit_button);
button_container->add(cancel_button);
sheet_container->add(button_container);

Page *test_page = new Page();
test_page->setContent(sheet_container);
Sheet *sheet = new Sheet();
sheet->setContent(test_page);
sheet->open();
```

This answers your question about making the layout but i would suggest you to take a look at UI guidelines and use something like [Dialog](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__dialog.html) for this. Also I would suggest to use QML for layout design instead of C++ if you don't have specific requirements that are hard to in QML.